# Play H264 Video/Audio Stream (from existing RTP session) on Xamarin Android device (4.4+)

Tags: android, xamarin, h.264, rtp

I am developing an App on Xamarin right now for Android, alter IOS.
I have started a SIP session as a Client successfully and got a SDP.

With the session description I start my RTPClient (I am using Managed Media Aggregation (https://net7mma.codeplex.com/) also successfully it seems.

I get an URI ending with a Media Port.

I have tried different ways to Play back that stream:

Android.Widget.VideoView:

```
videoview.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(fullPath));
videoview.Start();
```

says in a popup box "Cannot Playback Video" or something like this just in german in my case.

So I tried an Android.Media.MediaPlayer:

```
player.Reset();
player.SetDataSource(fullPath);
player.Prepare();
```

runs into an exception and

```
player.PrepareAsync();
```

seems to run nowhere.

Should These work somehow and am I just doing wrong?

Or must I give it more info like it is H.264 decoded, has 640x480 Pixels and more stuff I know exactly from my SDP media description?

I have taken a look into that MediaFormat and MediaCodec classes from Android but still do not know how to use them exactly for my case (RTP Connection with known Media description).

Thanks a lot and have a nice Weekend!

Eric

Answer (score 1):

You should use an external component like the Google ExoPlayer to media with encoding. There is a Nuget package available for this: https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin

Answer (score 0):

That's my project... (net7mma) e.g. I am the Author...

You can use either the Rtsp or Rtp client quite easily and I have verified such in Android recently.

If you have specific questions make a thread in the project's home page and I will address it.